# jQuery Autocomplete to jQuery UI Autocomplete migration (jQuery 1.2.x to 2.x)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to migrate an old script to use the latest [jquery.ui.autocomplete.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js) and [jQuery 2.1.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js) (loading jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js helps but I am looking not to use it).

Here is what I am trying to get done, find:

```
$("input").autocomplete(["a", "b", "c"]);
```

and change to:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
  source: ["a", "b", "c"]
});
```

- per [jQuery autocomplete migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide/)

Here are three pieces of my old code:

```
$("#county").autocomplete(CountyArray, {            
        width: 170,
        matchContains: false,
        selectFirst: false
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if($("#county").val()!=''){
            $("#place").val('');
            $("#street").val('');
            $('#islike').val('0');
            LoadPlaceListNew(0);
        }
    });
```

...

```
$("#street").autocomplete(siteURL+"auto_street.php?county="+county+"&place="+place,{
        width: 260,
        selectFirst: false      
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {        
            $("#street").val(formatted.split(" (")[0]);
            if($("#street").val()!=''){ 
                LoadZipcodesNew(0);
            }           
    });
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your older code version and an another with a newer version of what have you tried so far. And please specify on which stage are you facing the problem

Comment: It may be a different issue, still looking at it, the first cause was "unautocomplete" being removed from jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out, only latest jQuery and jquery.ui.autocomplete.js is needed (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js is a workaround that is not necessary at all):

```
$("#county").autocomplete({
        source: CountyArray,
        /*
        width: 170,
        matchContains: false,
        selectFirst: false
        */
        select: function(event, data) {
            if($("#county").val()!=''){
                $("#place").val('');
                $("#street").val('');
                $('#islike').val('0');
                LoadPlaceListNew(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

...

```
$("#street").autocomplete({
    source: siteURL+"auto_street.php?county="+county+"&county="+county,
    /*
    width: 260,
    selectFirst: false
    */
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var strit = ui.item.value;
        strit = strit.split(" (")[0];
        if (ui.item && ui.item.value){
            titleinput = ui.item.value;
            $("#street").val(strit);
            ui.item.value= $.trim(strit);
        } 
        if($("#street").val()!=''){ 
            LoadZipcodesNew(0);
        }
    }   
});
```